# Single sign on to web application with windows login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webapi2

I have a single sign-off requirement from our customers as part of our next release. The existing flow is as follows:

1. User logs into their organization system (ad user) or main portal system using their email ID or user name as provided by the organization.
2. User clicks the link to my web (i.e. angular + web api)
3. User is automatically taken as a logged in user and he can access protected pages.  If the user wants to log in from outside the organization he must use the login form on our site.

I have completed the login form web application using the email/password that we have stored in our local system, but I am still struggling to implement with window credential's.

My project is based on web api 2.0 with an angular fronted. It's hosted on IIS.  I don't want to use any 3rd party DLLs to manage everything, so are there any appropriate solutions available in the .NET environment which would achieve my requirements in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

If your website needs to seamlessly authenticate user credentials in an AD domain, one way to achieve this is by creating a small IIS server with NTLM authentication inside the domain and forward some type of authorization/credential key to your outside website.

Comment: i am struggling to identify the username that's through i can authenticate user credentials in an AD. i am using to get username but it shows me IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool                                
var user =System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

Comment: You should be able to pull the user domain/identity in the codebehind by using 
`User.Identity.Name`.

You can verify the user is in a role by 
`if (User.IsInRole(<rolename>))`.

You can use, for example, an LDAP connection to your AD host through DirectoryServices to pull any specific information about the user that you may want to pass to your page.